# How to pass an image and data to another view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image

In my iPhone application, the first screen the user selects one out of two options from a segmented controller, one option from a data picker (using an array), enters in their name and uploads a picture from their photo gallery to a UIImageView.

My question is how do I get all this data to the next view (to get to the next view I have an IBAction set up and linked to a UIButton). I don't have trouble telling what the user picked, but it's getting all their options (especially the image) into my second view.

Answer (score 3):

Create a image variable in second view, write property for it & synthesize it.

```
**(SecondView.h)**


UIImage *myImage;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *myImage;


**(SecondView.m)**

@synthesize myImage;
```

Then, when you allocate new view (on button click), pass the selected image to second view.

```
SecondView *mvController = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView” 
                                    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
mvController.myImage = yourSelectedImage;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvController animated:YES];
```

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

When you create the next view in the IBAction, you can set the properties of that view using the data available in your current view. For example:

```
CustomView *secondview = [CustomView alloc] init];
secondview.backgroundimage = // Set your image here
secondview.data = // set the data here
[self.view addsubview secondview];
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables that you are using to display data i.e. string to display name and `UIImage` in `UIImageView`. propertise and synthesize this variable and by creating an instance of next class in your class you can set the value of these variables of class2 from class1. and assign these values in text property and image property in `viewwillappear` of second class.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method in the second view e.g.:

```
-(SecondView*)initWithImage:(UIImage*)img anndOption(int)opt ...
```

In the UIAction you could instantiate the view like the following:

```
SecondView *mySecondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithImage:img andOption:opt ...];
```

and then show up the view.